# Is it possible to increase Samsung's limit on contact merging?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2

On Samsung phones, at least I know on the Galaxy S and Galaxy SII, it is only possible to merge 5 contacts max. There is also an issue on the Google Code page of Android [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16735), but this did not solve the Samsung specific problem.

The suggested fix on XDA-Developers did not work with newer Android versions, and I'd like to stick with the official Samsung ROM.

Is there way to increase the limit on contact merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, if you have root Access.

Found the following solution on [l0uy blog](http://blog.l0uy.com/2013/02/link-more-than-5-contacts-in-android-on-samsung-galaxy-phones.php):

Open `/system/csc/others.xml` and add the following child to the `<FeatureSet>` parant:

```
<CscFeature_Contact_SetLinkCountMaxAs>30</CscFeature_Contact_SetLinkCountMaxAs>
```

The `30` is the limit, how much contacts you will merge. choose what you want.

Works fine on 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.4.2 note2 I did it by adding the value to another file called feature.xml in the same csc folder. In fact, the statement is already mentioned but with the value 5, so all what you have to change is the max. No. From 5 to anything you like, then save then restart the phone.